# iOS Subscription for app features

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, content-type, subscription

I am looking at a subscription model for in-app functionality. It seems that this would be allowed as you could definitely use in-App purchase to buy extra features. Has anyone had any direct experience with this or know of other apps that do this?

It would not be a digital media subscription as all you would be subscribing to would be application features.

Comment: We have an app with in-app purchase that unlocks features. We're about 2 weeks from launching a version that allows you to subscribe instead to unlock those features. I'm happy to get back to you if/when it's approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and Apple will allow it.

You will need to implement possibility that user when reinstalling iOS device can get purchased features back to his device.

Other than this it's simple non-consumable iap.

Comment: do you have first hand experience, or know of an example where this is the case?

Comment: I had an app that I have developed for a customer rejected few times until they explicitly said that I should use non-consumable iap type. After that it was a go.

Comment: yes but if it is non-consumable doesn't that mean it won't expire? as we want them to keep subscribing for features month to month.

Comment: then you will have to use non-renewable subscription and implement your own mechanism for controlling if subscription has expired and so on

Comment: so you do not have any direct experience with doing this or know of any other apps that do......??

Comment: I have direct experience with app that has non-renewable subscription for features unlocked every month. Apple wouldn't allow auto-renewable subscription for this because they say "Auto-renewable subscriptions should be used for dynamically changed content, news, magazines, radio content, etc." and therefore they rejected my app with clear instruction that non-renewable subscription should be used. After I changed that application was reviewed and it's in App store now.

Comment: Cool: So in summary, I will use a non renewable subscription that the user will have to renew for every time period they wish to use it in.

Comment: Yes, you will have to implement how user will know that he needs to renew, on our app which is connecting to server server is the one that sends the message which code recognizes and offer user to renew.